# Уточнение меток в вопросах - за/против

Tags: обсуждение

Обратил внимание, что при утверждении моих правок, когда меняется только состав меток в вопросе некоторые проверяющие голосуют против. В связи с вопрос когда стоит удалять/добавлять метки? Стоит ли изменять метки у отвеченных/старых впросов?

Comment: Если метка помогает определить тему вопроса, её стоит добавить, если нет, её стоить удалить.